# Im getting "no viable alternative at character '&quot;'" while executing apex class for batch class

Tags: apex, unit-test, batch, code-coverage

I have Created a Batch and test class for code coverage. However Im getting the following error message while executing the test apex.

"no viable alternative at character '"'"

Batch Apex:

```
//Overdue opportunity reminder batch
```

//Owner: samuel
global class OverdueOppNotification implements Database.Batchable, Database.Stateful {

```
 //Variable Section
global FINAL String strQuery;
global List<String> errorMessages = new List<String>();

global OverdueOppNotification() { 
    this.strQuery = getBatchQuery();
}

 //Returns the Query String to Batch constructor to fetch right records.
private String getBatchQuery() {
    String strQuery = 'SELECT Id, CloseDate, StageName, Owner.Email FROM Opportunity WHERE CloseDate < TODAY AND StageName != "5. Won - Execution" AND StageName != "6. Won - Cash" AND StageName  != "Closed Lost" AND StageName != "Closed / Not realized" '; 
    return strQuery;
}
//Batch Start method
global Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext BC) {
    return Database.getQueryLocator(strQuery);
}
//Batch Execute method calls findCostForWoD method
global void execute(Database.BatchableContext BC, List<sObject> scopeList) {
    System.debug(LoggingLevel.INFO, '== scopeList size ==' + scopeList.size());
    
    List<Opportunity> oppList = (List<Opportunity>) scopeList;
    if(!oppList.isEmpty()) { 
        List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage> mailList = new List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage>();
        for (Opportunity prod : oppList)
        {               
            
            Messaging.SingleEmailMessage message = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage(); 
            String[] toAddresses = new String[] {prod.Owner.Email};
                message.setTemplateId('00X1w000000IdaZ');
            Message.setToAddresses(toAddresses); 
            Message.SaveAsActivity = false;
            mailList.add(Message);
            
        }
        if(!mailList.isEmpty()) {
            try{
                Messaging.sendEmail(mailList);
            }
            catch (Exception ex) {
                errorMessages.add('Unable to send email to Tech: '+ ex.getStackTraceString());
            }
        }
    }
}  
 //Batch Finish method for after execution of batch work
global void finish(Database.BatchableContext BC) { 
}
```

}

Test Calss:

```
@isTest
```

public class Test_OverdueOppNotification {

```
@isTest
static void Test_overdueOppNotification() {
    
    // create custom setting
    Country_sales_margin__c  cs = new Country_sales_margin__c(CS_CCR_Norway__c=7.8);
    insert cs;
    
    // new User
    // Owner of the Opportunity/Account 1
    User testOwnerNorth = TestUtils.createSampleUser('testOwnerOPPNorth', 'CCR Sales User');
    testOwnerNorth.Email = 'testownerbis@ccr.com';
    testOwnerNorth.CCR_Local_Area__c = 'North';
    testOwnerNorth.CCR_Country__c = 'CCR Austria';
    testOwnerNorth.USER_VR_Bypass__c = true;
    Insert testOwnerNorth;
    
    // new Account
    // Account linked to the Opportunity
    Account testAcc = new Account();
    testAcc.Name = 'testAccount';
    testAcc.Ownerid = testOwnerNorth.id;
    testAcc.ACC_Synchronize_Contact_Address__c=false;
    testAcc.BillingCountry = 'Norway'; // Margin Country 7.8        
    testAcc.Customer_Type__c = 'Retailer';
    insert testAcc;
    
   // new Opportunity
     //List<Opportunity> op_List = New List<Opportunity>();       
    Opportunity testOpp = new Opportunity();
    testOpp.ownerId =testOwnerNorth.id;
    testOpp.Name = 'Opp to test';
    testOpp.Opportunity_Short_Description__c  = 'Opptest';
    testOpp.Accountid =testAcc.id;
    testOpp.stageName ='0. Qualification';
    testOpp.type = 'New Business';
    testOpp.Sales_Process__c = 'Light - English';
    testOpp.Market_Segment__c = 'Turnkey Industrial';
    testOpp.CurrencyIsoCode = 'EUR';
    testOpp.CloseDate = Date.today() +1;
    testOpp.Amount = 300000;
    testOpp.Sales_Margin__c = 10;
    Insert testOpp;
    //op_List.add(testOpp);
    
    Test.startTest();
     //Database.SaveResult []str = Database.insert(op_List,false);
   // system.assertEquals(True, str[0].isSuccess());
    OverdueOppNotification overdue = new OverdueOppNotification();
    database.executeBatch(overdue);
    
    Test.stopTest();
    
    
}
```

}

Please advise.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error seems to be in the query string. You are using double-quotes `"` character which is not recognized by the apex, it only recognizes single-quote `'`. There are several ways you can fix this.

Use `'` escaped character

```
String strQuery = 'SELECT Id, CloseDate, StageName, Owner.Email FROM Opportunity WHERE CloseDate < TODAY AND StageName != \'5. Won - Execution\' AND StageName != \'6. Won - Cash\' AND StageName  != \'Closed Lost\' AND StageName != \'Closed / Not realized\'';
```

Or create a set of string and use it as [binding variable](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_dynamic_soql.htm)

```
String stageNames= new Set<String>();
// Add values in set
List<sObject> sobjList = Database.query('SELECT Id FROM Opportunity WHERE StageName in  :stageNames');
```

Comment: @ Manjit5190 this has fixed the issue, however, I could not get 100 % code coverage the Execute part of batch class did not covered with the test class I have writen.

Comment: Your query looks for records where the Close date is less than today but your test data has close date as `Date.today() +1` so you get no results. You should create a separate question for this.

Comment: @ Manjit5190 that worked absolutely fine. Thank you.